# Express / Node.js - Render page with data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a list of `Teams` displayed as a list of links on my page, at the moment, I have a textbox....when the link for that `Team` is clicked, the `Key` for that `Team` is taken and sent to the `/team/:key` route, it searches for the `Team` by `Key`, gets the data and sends the data back. If the data was successfully sent back to the JS file then the `Team` name is output to the textbox.

I want to change this, when the link is clicked and the data has been retrieved using `Team.findByKey` I want to render a new page ('teamDetails') and pass it the data for that `Team`. This way I can make it so that each link for a `Team` links to the `Team's` individual page with their full details on it.

Any idea how I would adapt this `/team/:key` route to do this?

`JS file`

```
// Setup teamsLink to retrieve Team info for whichever Team was clicked
Team.initTeamsLink = function(){
  $("a.teamLink").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var teamId = ($(this)[0]).getAttribute('id');

    $.get('/team/'+teamId, function(response){
      if(response.retStatus === 'success'){
        var teamData = response.teamData;
        $('#teamId').val(teamData.key);
        $('#teamName').val(teamData.name);
      } else if(response.retStatus === 'failure'){

      }
    });  
  });
 };
```

`Route`

```
  app.get('/team/:key', function(req, res) {
    util.log('Serving request for url [GET] ' + req.route.path);
    Team.findByKey(req.params.key, function(err, teamData){
      if(!err && teamData){
        teamData = teamData;
        res.json({
          'retStatus' : 'success',
          'teamData' : teamData
        });
      } else {
        util.log('Error in fetching Team by key : ' + req.params.key);
        res.json({
          'retStatus' : 'failure',
          'msg' : 'Error in fetching Team by key ' + req.params.key
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Instead of a JSON response, you want a HTML site?

Comment: Yes, when the link is clicked at the moment, a JSON response is sent to the page in order to put the Team's name into a textbox. Instead I want to render a HTML page I have (teamDetails.jade is the page), I want to pass the Team's details to this page when rendering so that I can create a page for each team when the links are clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `res.json()`, you could use a templating engine which would render the individual team's page. Say you want to use [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) templates:

```
npm install ejs
```

Next, create `views/team.ejs`, which would contain the EJS template for the team. In your route, replace `res.json()` with a call to the templating engine:

```
res.render('team.ejs', { 'teamData' : teamData });
```

**EDIT**: just read your comment about using Jade templates: the code is very similar, just replace `team.ejs` with `teamDetails.jade`.

Also, you probably can remove your client-side code which handles click events on the links, since you don't want to perform an AJAX request anymore.

Comment: Yes, I have replaced the `res.json()` code with `res.render('teamDetails');` but nothing happens when the links are clicked. I added in a simple little `util.log('rendering page')` to check it is actually getting to this point of the code and it is, but the page isn't being rendered. Any idea? What do you mean about removing the client-side code? I will still need to listen for when a Team link is clicked surely?

Comment: I would just generate proper HREF's in those links to point to the team-pages, but if that's not possible (should be though, since you're placing the team id's in the `id` attribute), replace `$.get()` with `location.href = "/team/" + teamId;`.

Comment: Interesting, I will look at this as well then, do you know why the page isn't rendering like I said?

Comment: You're trying to perform an AJAX request (using `$.get()`) on what is now a route that generates HTML, whereas your client side code still assumes a JSON response.

Comment: Would you be able to help change the code? I've been trying to fiddle around with the code for some time now and I'm getting nowhere, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry to post again, but using your method, how would you pass the `teamData` to the rendered page and use it to output for example the name of the `Team` on the page? Have currently tried using `#{teamData.name}` to output the name with a typeError occurring.

Comment: It really depends on what `teamData`, as returned by `findByKey`, actually is. Try this as test: `res.render('teamDetails.jade', { teamData : { name : 'My Team' }});`

Comment: I have this: `res.render('teamDetails', { 'teamData' : teamData } );` I have output `teamData` to the console before this line and it correctly outputs something with {name, _id, key} in it. But I cannot get it to output the name of the team on the web page, I have tried putting #{teamData.name} so far but can't get it to output the name still.

Comment: I've run out of ideas for now, try running my test to see if *anything* gets rendered.

Comment: If I were to render `{output: '<h1>Hello World</h1>'}` it simply shows `<h1>Hello World</h1>` on the output. What do I do to parse it to html?

Comment: @LV98 entirely depends on the templating engine you use (because it needs to be able to output "raw" data)

Comment: @robertklep I use `Express-Handlebars` - just getting familiar with `React` .. think it will be a better investment in the long term.

Comment: @LV98 with Handlebars you can use `{{{output}}}` to [prevent HTML escaping](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping). I agree that it's certainly worth it to check out React in more detail :D

Answer (score 2):

Use handlebars templates - http://handlebarsjs.com/

```
npm install handlebars
npm install hbs
```

Coffe-script:

```
hbs = require 'hbs'

app.set 'views', __dirname + '/app/views' #folder with your views
app.set 'view engine', 'hbs'
app.use express.bodyParser()
app.use express.methodOverride()
```

In the router:

```
res.render 'index', {title: 'index'} #view name and context
```