# How do I return JSON data to Riot.js from Node.js express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, riot.js

I'm developing a web application with Riot.js on client side and Node.js express on server side.
Riot.js can mount JSON data and can use for rendering HTML. Actually I have some JSON data on server side, and want to use them with Riot.js.

Currently my express server's code is quite simple.

```
  var express = require('express'),                                                                                             
      serveIndex = require('serve-index'),                                                                                      
      app = express();                                                                                                          

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));                                                                               
  app.use(serveIndex(__dirname + '/public'));                                                                                   
  app.listen(3000);
```

I think HTML template is helpful for my question. But I couldn't find answer with Riot.js, how do I use and render data from server?

- [Node & Express - How do I send a page AND some JS data to the browser in a single request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270922/express-node-js-render-page-with-data)

I know how I mount data if the data is on client side like this:

```
    <script>                                                                                                                   
      riot.mount('my_hoge', {                                                                                                
        data: [                                                                                                                
          { name: 'A', url: 'xxxx'},                                                                                           
          { name: 'B', url: 'yyy', isActive: true},                                                                          
          { name: 'C', url: 'zzzz'}                                                                                           
        ]                                                                                                                            })                                                                                                                       
   </script>
```

**environment**

- Node.js v5.3.0
- express v4.13.3

Comment: do an ajax call from your client to your json and be happy .... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: here is an example from riotjs: http://riotjs.com/api/#tag-update

Comment: Great! I could. After I set API for returning test data on express server, I could re-render data on client side with ajax's callback by over-writing data of Riot.js

Comment: @jef Please capitalize HTML, JSON, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can load JSON data into your Riot.js element using AJAX like this:

```
var url = "http://yourserver:3000/";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        riot.mount('my_hoge', { data: data });
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of their examples, they use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API to get data from a server.

```
window.fetch('http://api.fixer.io/latest?base=USD')
  .then(function(response) { return response.json() })
  .then(function(data) {
    var rates = Object.keys(data.rates)
      .map(function (key) { return { title: key, price: data.rates[key] }})
      .sort(function(a, b) { return a.price - b.price })
    self.update({ rates: rates })
})
```

[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) to the repo